# Angular Translate synchronicity issue in JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internationalization, angular-translate

Angular Translate works great as a filter in the view.
I am using angular-translate-loader-static-files with external files like `locale-en.json` etc.

The problem is when I try to do something like this:

```
var placeholder = $translate('placeholder.NAME')
                    .then(function (translatedValue) {
                        return translatedValue;
                    });
```

I always get a promise back, and in the UI it shows as `{}` instead of the word NAME for english etc.

What is the correct way to translate in JS using angular-translate?

EDIT:
Tried this and got the following result (still not solved)

```
 var placeholder = '';
                $translate('placeholder.NAME').then(function (translatedValue) {
                    console.log(translatedValue);
                    placeholder = translatedValue;
                }, function(err){
                    console.log(err); // returns placeholder.NAME
                });
                console.log(placeholder);  // returns empty string
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var placeholder = '';
$translate('placeholder.NAME').then(function (translatedValue) {
  placeholder = translatedValue;
});
```

Comment: @itamar It depends on how you eventually use the variable `placeholder`.  It probably should be `$scope.placeholder`.

Comment: It's actually used to be dropped into a scope array, so I keep it as a local variable.

Comment: @itamar I see. Then you should do that in the callback.

Comment: Okay, so I tried your solution and here's what I got: [put in question for readability]

Comment: @itamar And that's not ok?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to keep your controller free from translation logic and translate your strings directly inside your view like this:

```
<h1>{{ 'TITLE.HELLO_WORLD' | translate }}</h1>
```

Comment: yes. the point is that this is already working - I need to do translations in the controller way before the data is shown.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`instant`](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/api/pascalprecht.translate.$translate#methods_instant) function to get the value without the promise:

```
var translation = $translate.instant('placeholder.NAME');
```

However, this does not wait for the translation files to get loaded. You should make sure you are calling this after translation files are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

From the website http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/03_using-translate-service635

```
app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', '$translate', function ($scope, $translate) {
$translate(['HEADLINE', 'PARAGRAPH', 'NAMESPACE.PARAGRAPH']).then(function (translations) {
$scope.headline = translations.HEADLINE;
$scope.paragraph = translations.PARAGRAPH;
$scope.namespaced_paragraph = translations['NAMESPACE.PARAGRAPH'];
});
}]);
```